# Uploading different unique files to the server and their names saved to the database

Tags: php

Before you start screen duplicate post, please understand that I searched here and the google but could find something that helps my situation.
Even as I am typing, something close to what I need was written in asp.net.

Here is the scenario.

I have 5 different unique files, each of which is a fieldname on the datatabase.

Here is a sample markup:

```
<form id="form1" name="contacts_form" method="post" action="save.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
..
..
      <td class="td_input_form"><input type="file" name="item1" size="50"></td>
      <td class="td_input_form"><input type="file" name="item2" size="50"></td>
      <td class="td_input_form"><input type="file" name="item3" size="50"></td>
      <td class="td_input_form"><input type="file" name="item4" size="50"></td>
      <td class="td_input_form"><input type="file" name="item5" size="50"></td>
..
..
</form>
```

We would like to upload all 5 files to a folder called uploads and then save their filename as well as additional form fields to the database.

I am having issues getting this to work.

```
  <?php

// Connect to SQL Server database
include("../Connections/Connect.php")

//This is the directory where images will be saved
$target = "uploads";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);

//This gets all the other information from the form

    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];
        if ($file_type!="application/pdf" || $file_type!="image/gif" || $file_type!="image/jpeg") {
         $errors[] 'You can only upload PDFs, JPEGs or GIF files.<br>';
        }
        if($file_size > 2097152){
            $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }   
$name='". ms_escape_string($_POST['nameMember']) ."';
$bandMember='". ms_escape_string($_POST['bandMember']) ."';
$pic1='". ms_escape_string(($_FILES['photo1']['name'])) ."';
$pic2='". ms_escape_string(($_FILES['photo2']['name'])) ."';
$pic3='". ms_escape_string(($_FILES['photo3']['name'])) ."';
$pic4='". ms_escape_string(($_FILES['photo4']['name'])) ."';
$pic5='". ms_escape_string(($_FILES['photo5']['name'])) ."';
$about='". ms_escape_string($_POST['aboutMember'];
$bands='". ms_escape_string($_POST['otherBands']) ."';

//Writes the information to the database
$sql="INSERT INTO tableName (nameMember,bandMember,photo1,photo2,photo3,photo4,photo5,aboutMember,otherBands)
VALUES ('$name', '$bandMember', '$pic1', '$pic2', '$pic3', '$pic4', '$pic5', '$about', '$bands')" ;

$objQuery = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

//Writes the files to the server
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))
{

//If all is ok
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded to the directory and records saved to the database";
}
else {

//Gives and error if its not
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
sqlsrv_close($conn);
}
?>
```

Somehow, I have the feeling I am confusing the upload file code with the variables to be inserted into the database.
Thank you in advance for your help.

```
INSERT INTO bids (BidDate,DueDate,DueTime,BidTitle,BidID,Description,BidIDFile,photo1,SignInSheet,TabSheet,Department,Xcontract,ContactEmail,ContactPhone,NumofBids,AwardDate,AwardRecip1,BidType,LastUpdate,Notes,BidStatus) VALUES ('03/27/2015', '03/27/2015','2:00pm','Test','TTTTTTI9','Testing','524767-3252.htm', '240','Jim Brown','jim.brown@yahoo.com','987-254-3311','3','03/25/2015','Johhny, Carey, Jenny','Property Sales','03/24/2015','Testing notes','1')
```

I thought you might want to see the actual INSERT statement and the declarations.

```
            $sqlArr['values'][$i]   =   "'".ms_escape_string($_FILES['item']['name'][$i])."'";
            $sqlArr['columns'][]  =   "BidIDFile";
            $sqlArr['columns'][$i+=1]  =  "photo".$i;
            $sqlArr['columns'][]  =   "SignInSheet";
            $sqlArr['columns'][]  =   "TabSheet";

if(isset($sqlArr['columns'])) {
    // Because this is dependent on all images being uploaded properly, you
    // need more validation in your code. This code inserts no matter what.
    $sql="INSERT INTO bids (BidDate,DueDate,DueTime,BidTitle,BidID,Description,".implode(",",$sqlArr['columns']).",Department,Xcontract,ContactEmail,ContactPhone,NumofBids,AwardDate,AwardRecip1,BidType,LastUpdate,Notes,BidStatus)
              VALUES ('$bidDate', '$dueDate','$dueTime','$bidTitle','$bidId','$desc',".implode(",",$sqlArr['values']).", '$dept','$bidContact','$contactEmail','$contactPhone','$numBids','$awardDate','$awardrecip1','$bidType','$lastUpdate','$notes','$status'

)" ;
```

A couple of more pointers.

1, the fieldnames were coming in with single quotes. So, you may notice the implode columns doesn't have the single quotes anymore.

2, Also, we wanted the index position to start at 1 instead of 0 since photo fieldname begins as photo1, ...

```
Array
(
    [txtBidDate] => 03/27/2015
    [txtDueDate] => 03/27/2015
    [txtDueTime] => 2:00pm
    [BidTitle] => Test
    [BidID] => TTTTTTI9
    [Description] => Testing
    [Department] => 240
    [BidContact] => Jim Brown
    [ContactEmail] => jim.brown@yahoo.com
    [ContactPhone] => 987-254-3311
    [NumofBids] => 3
    [txtAwardDate] => 03/25/2015
    [AwardRecip] => Johhny, Carey, Jenny
    [BidType] => Property Sales
    [txtLastUpdate] => 03/24/2015
    [Notes] => Testing  notes
    [Status] => 1
)
Array
(
    [item] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 524767-3252.htm
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => text/html
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => C:\Windows\Temp\phpAB56.tmp
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 4
                    [2] => 4
                    [3] => 4
                    [4] => 4
                    [5] => 4
                    [6] => 4
                    [7] => 4
                    [8] => 4
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 60343
                )

        )

)


BidDate  
DueDate  
DueTime  
Project Title  
ID  
Description 

BidIDFILE - file upload
photo1  - file upload 
photo2 - file upload  
photo3  - file upload 
photo4  - file upload 
photo5  - file upload 
photo6 - file upload  

Department  

SignInSheet - file upload  

BidContact  
ContactEmail  
ContactPhone  
NumBidReceived  

TabulationSheet - file upload  

AwardDate  
AwardRecipient  
BidType  
LastUpdate  
Notes  
Status
```

///Code snip to upload files and insert records to the database:

$cols   =   (isset($cols) && is_array($cols))? implode(",",$cols):"";
$vals   =   (isset($vals) && is_array($vals))? implode(",",$vals):"";

```
//echo '<pre>';
//print_r($sql);
//print_r($cols);
//print_r($vals);
//echo '</pre>';
//echo '<br />';
//echo "insert into bids ($cols) values ($vals)";
        sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
        echo "Register Completed!<br>";
        header('Location: admin.php');
```

Comment: These are not right for one: `$name='". ms_escape_string($_POST['nameMember']) ."';` Should be `$name= ms_escape_string($_POST['nameMember']);` provided `ms_escape_string()` is a function.

Comment: `$about='". ms_escape_string($_POST['aboutMember'];` has a syntax error.

Comment: `include("../Connections/Connect.php")` missing semicolon so syntax error.

Comment: `$errors[] 'You can only upload PDFs, JPEGs or GIF files.<br>';` missing equal sign (`=`) so syntax error.

Comment: I'm also trying to get this code working. But unfortunately it is a huge mess. There are syntax errors left and right, `photos` is undefined in your form, `files` aswell, etc. So I eventually gave up. @Tairoc: Before asking for help you should provide a simple WORKING code snippet for an easy reproduction for those who are trying to help you here, and not expect us to fix your coding errors.

Comment: Finally, you are missing an end bracket `}` so syntax error.

Comment: Actually, not finally....there is no named input for these `$_FILES['photo1']`

Comment: In regards to the what do I do now question, my code assembles the query, you just need to use your db connection, presumably the `sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);` to insert the `$sql = "insert into table ($cols) values ($vals)"` string into your DB.

Comment: @Rasclatt, thank you for everything.

You have been a God Sent. I will still be struggling today if it weren't for your heavenly patience.

If you don't mind, I am leaving my email address so you can use it to send me yours.

I PROMISE I won't ask you any technical questions.

I will just like to know what I can do to show appreciation, not just for your assistance but unbelievable patience you showed.

THANK YOU very much.

BTW: I commented out the echo ="insert...(cols) values (vals)" and uploading is working but not insert to the DB.

Comment: Sure post your email and I will copy it. Then I'll let you know I've done so so you can delete the post so no one starts spamming your address. I'm always looking to expand my network.

Comment: I got it. You can delete it.

Comment: @Rasclatt, as kind as you have been, I know at some point you get tired so very sorry to keep coming back but I still have issues with inserting to the database.

The upload works as indicated yesterday but it is not inserting to the database. where do I put sqlsrv_query. I have tried a lot of things but only upload works. 

Please see small code snip above how I am adding sql_query ($conn,$sql).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a ton of things messed up, but this should be a working script. Aside from my above comments, I have notated below for additional information and concern:

**FORM**

```
<form id="form1" name="contacts_form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <table>
      <tr>
      <!-- You need to array these. The method you have is too manual 
            You could even use for() to create these -->
      <td class="td_input_form"><input type="file" name="item[]" size="50"></td>
      <td class="td_input_form"><input type="file" name="item[]" size="50"></td>
      <td class="td_input_form"><input type="file" name="item[]" size="50"></td>
      <td class="td_input_form"><input type="file" name="item[]" size="50"></td>
      <td class="td_input_form"><input type="file" name="item[]" size="50"></td>
      </tr>
      </table>
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
// I can't check this for you...
include("../Connections/Connect.php");

    // In general, you have no check to see that anything was submitted.
    // That is something you may want to implement or else this script
    // will autoload on page load regardless of $_FILES or $_POST submission

    // You may want to add document root
    $target = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads";
    // I am filtering the files incase there are empty uploads
    // You need to have the proper file input name (item)
    $_FILES['item']['name'] =   array_filter($_FILES['item']['name']);
    $_FILES['item']['type'] =   array_filter($_FILES['item']['type']);
    $_FILES['item']['size'] =   array_filter($_FILES['item']['size']);
    $_FILES['item']['tmp_name'] =   array_filter($_FILES['item']['tmp_name']);

    foreach($_FILES['item']['name'] as $i => $value ) {
            $file_name              =   $_FILES['item']['name'][$i];
            $file_size              =   $_FILES['item']['size'][$i];
            $file_tmp               =   $_FILES['item']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $file_type              =   $_FILES['item']['type'][$i];

            $name                   =   ms_escape_string($_POST['nameMember']);
            $bandMember             =   ms_escape_string($_POST['bandMember']);
            $about                  =   ms_escape_string($_POST['aboutMember']);
            $bands                  =   ms_escape_string($_POST['otherBands']);
            $sqlArr['values'][$i]   =   "'".ms_escape_string($_FILES['item']['name'][$i])."'";
            $sqlArr['columns'][$i]  =   "photo".$i;
            // At this point you are only notifying user.
            // You have no code to prevent this limitation. 
            if ($file_type!="application/pdf" || $file_type!="image/gif" || $file_type!="image/jpeg")
                 $errors[] =    'You can only upload PDFs, JPEGs or GIF files.<br>';
            // So far, this is just for notification, you haven't
            // actually done anything about this limitation
            if($file_size > 2097152)
                $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';

            // Makes the folder if not already made.
            if(!is_dir($target))
                mkdir($target,0755,true);

            //Writes the files to the server
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['item']['tmp_name'][$i], $target."/".$file_name)) {
                //If all is ok
                echo "The file ". $file_name. " has been uploaded to the directory and records saved to the database";
            }
            else {

            //Gives and error if its not
            echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
            }
        }

if(isset($sqlArr['columns'])) {
    // Because this is dependent on all images being uploaded properly, you
    // need more validation in your code. This code inserts no matter what.
    $sql="INSERT INTO tableName (nameMember,bandMember,`".implode("`,`",$sqlArr['columns'])."`,aboutMember,otherBands)
VALUES ('$name', '$bandMember',".implode(",",$sqlArr['values']).", '$about', '$bands')" ;
    $objQuery = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
    sqlsrv_close($conn);
} ?>
```

---

**EDIT:** For further clarification on how to process the post and files try using processing functions that will return an array for use in an sql statement:

**FORM:**
Add this line in the form:

```
<td class="td_input_form"><input type="file" name="BidIDFile[]"></td>
```

**PROCESSING:**

```
function ProcessRequest($request = array())
    {
        // See how many post variables are being sent
        if(count($request) > 0) {
                // Loop through post
                foreach($request as $key => $value) {
                        // Create insert values
                        $insert['vals'][]   =   "'".ms_escape_string($value)."'";
                        // Create insert columns
                        $insert['cols'][]   =   "`".str_replace("txt","",$key)."`";
                        // For good measure, create an update string
                        $insert['update'][] =   "`".str_replace("txt","",$key)."`".' = '."'".ms_escape_string($value)."'";

                        // For modern day binding, you can use this array
                        $insert['bind']['cols'][]           =   "`".$key."`";
                        $insert['bind']['cols_bind'][]      =   ":".$key;
                        $insert['bind']['vals'][":".$key]   =   $value;
                        $insert['bind']['update'][]         =   "`".$key.'` = :'.$key;
                    }
                // If there are cols/values return them
                if(isset($insert))
                    return $insert;
            }
    }

function ProcessFiles($name = 'item',$target = '/uploads')
    {
        $target =   $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$target;

        // Makes the folder if not already made.
        if(!is_dir($target))
            mkdir($target,0755,true);

        // If the files array has been set
        if(isset($_FILES[$name]['name']) && !empty($_FILES[$name]['name'])) {
                // Remove empties
                $_FILES[$name]['name']      =   array_filter($_FILES[$name]['name']);
                $_FILES[$name]['type']      =   array_filter($_FILES[$name]['type']);
                $_FILES[$name]['size']      =   array_filter($_FILES[$name]['size']);
                $_FILES[$name]['tmp_name']  =   array_filter($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name']);

                // You need to differentiate your type array names
                $use_name   =   ($name == 'item')? 'photo':$name;
                // To start at photo1, create an $a value of 1
                $a = 1;
                if(!empty($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name'])) {
                         foreach($_FILES[$name]['name'] as $i => $value ) {
                                $file_name  =   ms_escape_string($_FILES[$name]['name'][$i]);
                                $file_size  =   $_FILES[$name]['size'][$i];
                                $file_tmp   =   $_FILES[$name]['tmp_name'][$i];
                                $file_type  =   $_FILES[$name]['type'][$i];

                                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name'][$i], $target."/".$file_name)) {
                                        // Format the key values for photo
                                        if($name == 'item')
                                            $arr[$use_name.$a]      =   $file_name;
                                        // Format the key values for others
                                        else
                                            $arr[$use_name] =   $file_name;

                                        $sql                =   ProcessRequest($arr);
                                        // Auto increment the $a value
                                        $a++;
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            }

        if(isset($sql) && (isset($i) && $i == (count($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name'])-1)))
            return $sql;
    }

// Process files and post (or array in general)
$sql['post']        =   ProcessRequest($_POST);
$sql['file']        =   ProcessFiles('item');
$sql['BidIDFile']   =   ProcessFiles('BidIDFile');

if(isset($sql['post']['cols']))
    $cols[] =   implode(",",$sql['post']['cols']);

if(isset($sql['file']['cols']))
    $cols[] =   implode(",",$sql['file']['cols']);

if(isset($sql['BidIDFile']['cols']))
    $cols[] =   implode(",",$sql['BidIDFile']['cols']);


if(isset($sql['post']['vals']))
    $vals[] =   implode(",",$sql['post']['vals']);

if(isset($sql['file']['vals']))
    $vals[] =   implode(",",$sql['file']['vals']);

if(isset($sql['BidIDFile']['vals']))
    $vals[] =   implode(",",$sql['BidIDFile']['vals']);

$cols   =   (isset($cols) && is_array($cols))? implode(",",$cols):"";
$vals   =   (isset($vals) && is_array($vals))? implode(",",$vals):"";

echo '<pre>';
print_r($sql);
print_r($cols);
print_r($vals);
echo '</pre>';
echo '<br />';
echo "insert into table ($cols) values ($vals)";
```

Will give you something like (I only put two post key/value pairs, that's why there is only two. In your case there would be a series of pairs):

```
Array
    (
        [post] => Array
            (
                [vals] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 'asdfsda'
                        [1] => 'sdfsdfsdf'
                    )

                [cols] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => `BidType`
                        [1] => `BidDate`
                    )

                [update] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => `BidType` = 'asdfsda'
                        [1] => `BidDate` = 'sdfsdfsdf'
                    )

            )

        [file] => Array
            (
                [vals] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => '2015012203932.jpg'
                        [1] => 'a1400by1050.jpg'
                    )

                [cols] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => `photo1`
                        [1] => `photo2`
                    )

                [update] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => `photo1` = '2015012203932.jpg'
                        [1] => `photo2` = 'a1400by1050.jpg'
                    )

            )

        [BidIDFile] => Array
            (
                [vals] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => '87682315.jpg'
                    )

                [cols] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => `BidIDFile`
                    )

                [update] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => `BidIDFile` = '87682315.jpg'
                    )
            )
    )

insert into table (`BidType`,`BidDate`,`photo1`,`photo2`,`BidIDFile`) values ('','','2015012203932.jpg','a1400by1050.jpg','87682315.jpg')
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73348/discussion-on-answer-by-rasclatt-uploading-different-unique-files-to-the-server).